Understanding socket.SOL_SOCKET and socket.SO_REUSEADDR in Python
I'm currently working on a network application in Python, and I've come across the socket module's constants socket.SOL_SOCKET and socket.SO_REUSEADDR. I'm a bit confused about their purpose and how to use them correctly. Could someone explain what they do and provide an example of how they are typically used?
Here's what I understand so far:
socket.SOL_SOCKET: This is a socket option level. But I'm not sure what "level" means in this context.
socket.SO_REUSEADDR: This option seems to allow a socket to be bound to an address that is already in use. But why would I want to do that?

This is standard socket API, not specific to Python. Therefore marked as duplicate of questions which explain SO_REUSEADDR and SOL_SOCKET outside of python.
